# URL rewriting with space & "+" symbol in web.config

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to redirect my **old url**
"http://staging.TempSite.com/about-us/Institute-+target/%20"

to **new url** ""http://staging.TempSite.com/about-us/news-events""

```
<rule name="rule59" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="staging.TempSite.com/about-us/Institute-\+target/\s*" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="./about-us/news-events" />
```

i also tried followoing patterns.

```
pattern="staging.TempSite.com/about-us/Institute-\+target/\s*$" 
pattern="staging.TempSite.com/about-us/Institute-\+target/ $"
```

Comment: Try replacing `<match url="(.*)" />` with `<match url="^about-us/Institute-\+target/\s*$" />` and then `<action type="Redirect" url="/about-us/news-events" redirectType="Permanent" />`

Answer (score 1):

@Wiktor Stribiżew comment is almost correct, but it will not work. If you have `+` in your URL, you need to enable `allowDoubleEscaping` in your config. Example of config:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
    <rewrite>
       <rules>
            <rule name="rule59" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^about-us/Institute\-\+target/\s*$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/about-us/news-events" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: + issue is solved.. but if i tired http://staging.TempSite.com/about-us/Institute-+target/%20 then not working...   Only working for http://staging.TempSite.com/about-us/Institute-+target/  if i remove %20 from my url.

Comment: I tested it again and it's working for me. May be you have other rewrite rules which is preventing execution. Can you clear your browser cache? Because usually browsers cache 301 redirects

Comment: Yes i tried after clearing cache & incognito mode. And i also tried with removing other rules but %20 in end of line of URL is not working for me.

Comment: And your regexp is exactly as i posted `^about-us/Institute\-\+target/\s*$` ?

Comment: http://staging.TempSite.com/about-us/news-events/PgrID/6122/PageID/1/ArtMID/6121/ArticleID/270/StayinFront-Retail-Execution-Solutions-Awarded-Best-In-Class-for-Analytical-Insights-Guided-Selling-and-Mobile-UX-by-Promotion-Optimization-Institute-+target/%20

Comment: For this url you need different regexp. Initially in your question u posted another url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150560/discussion-between-victor-leontyev-and-juhi).